# Operaciones entre elementos de distintas listas Python

Tags: python, lista

Necesito realizar una operación divisoria entre items de dos listas diferentes.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('este_mes_subastas2.csv', sep=',')

a = list(df['Subastas'])
b = list(df['Impresiones'])
print a

>>> 
[39496098, 82823040, 81547406, 87863582, 84646788, 46192389, 42343494, 84741570, 90058153, 90184289, 87520960]
print b

>>>
[39496098, 456, 81521406, 63125282, 112236788, 678765389, 42343494, 84741570, 90058153, 90184289, 87520960]
```

Busco hacer esta función matemática para todos los elementos de las listas `(a[0] / b[0])*100`. La siguiente formula seria `(a[1] / b[1])*100`, `(a[2] / b[2])*100` y así sucesivamente hasta el elemento 11 de ambas listas

Comment: Martin, no tiene mucho sentido que crees listas Python cuando trabajas con pandas y puedes vectorizar la operación de forma muy simple creando una nueva columna o serie con los resultados. Usar listas es mucho más ineficiente. Te recomiendo que agregues siempre lo que has intentado a la pregunta, en caso contrario puede no ser bien recibida. Un saludo.

Comment: y como podría hacer para vetorizarla como dices? Necesito dividir el valor  D con C y multiplicado por 100. Todo eso pegarlo en la columna G. Me explico? @FJSevilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comenté no tiene sentido crear listas Python e iterar sobre ellas, lo que es tremendamente ineficiente, cuando vectorizar la operación en Pandas es trivial:

```
df["Resultado"] = df.Subastas / df.Impresiones * 100
```

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO # Python 2
else:
    from io import StringIO       # Python 3


csv = StringIO('''\
Subastas,Impresiones
405,52
75,87
0,5
0,45
785,0
454,96
2,5
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=',')
df["Resultado"] = df.Subastas / df.Impresiones * 100
```

Resultado:

```
>>> df

   Subastas  Impresiones   Resultado
0       405           52  778.846154
1        75           87   86.206897
2         0            0    0.000000
3         0           45    0.000000
4       785            0         inf
5       454           96  472.916667
6         2            5   40.000000
```

La división entre 0 no da error, se le asigna de valor `inf` (infinito).

Comment: Impecable! Cierro con tu respuesta! Muchas gracias

Comment: Crack, me podes ayudar con esto? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131673/comparacion-de-csv-renglones-agrupados-python

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
for itemA, itemB in zip(a,b):
     print((itemA / itemB) * 100)
```

lo que hace `zip()` con las dos listas es retornar un iterador de tuplas que puedes verlo haciendo esto:

```
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[(39496098, 39496098), (82823040, 456), (81547406, 81521406), (87863582, 63125282), (84646788, 112236788), (46192389, 678765389), (42343494, 42343494), (84741570, 84741570), (90058153, 90058153), (90184289, 90184289), (87520960, 87520960)]
```