# Comparacion de CSV renglones agrupados. Python

Tags: python, csv

Ordene mi CSV para poder hacer algunas operaciones matematicas con `if - else`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Cliente_x_Pais_Sitio.csv', sep=',')
df1 = df.sort_values(by=['Cliente','Auth_domain','Sitio',"Country"])
df1.to_csv('test.csv')
```

CSV data (test.csv):

```
Cliente,Fecha,Auth_domain,Sitio,Country,ECPM_medio
FF,15/12/2017,@ff,ff_Color,AfganistÃ¡n,0.53
FF,15/01/2018,@ff,ff_Color,AfganistÃ¡n,0.5
FF,15/01/2017,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.34
FF,15/12/2017,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.38
FF,15/01/2018,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.37
```

Estos son los `if - else` que necesitaria, cabe destacar que lo que esta en parentesis son los valores de la columna `ECPM_Medio` con respecto a las fechas.
Basicamente, por cada `Cliente, Auth_domain, Sitio, Country` comparo los valores que haya de `ECPM_Medio` de cada Fecha

```
if (15/12/2017 ECPM) ≤ (15/01/2018 ECPM):
    if ((15/12/2017 ECPM)*0.8) ≥ (15/01/2017 ECPM):
        r = (15/01/2017 ECPM)
    else:
        r = ((15/12/2017 ECPM)*0.8)
else:
    if (15/01/2018 ECPM) ≥ (15/01/2017 ECPM):
        r = (15/01/2017 ECPM)
    else:
        r = (15/01/2018 ECPM)
```

Un Ejemplo con los valores:

```
if 0.53 ≤ 0.5:
    if 0.5 ≥ 0: #if we don't have the cell value I would like to add a 0 True
        r = 0.5
```

Trabajo con muchos datos asique una formula para multiples grupos y no escribir manualmente los datos que necesito.

Mi nuevo CSV deberia ser algo asi:

```
Cliente,Auth_domain,Sitio,Country,Recomendation_ECPM
FF,@ff,ff_Color,AfganistÃ¡n,0.5
FF,@ff,ff_Color,Alemania,0.34
```